# Can't Connect to SQL Server Remotely (TCP Error)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, database-connection, connection-string

I am having an issue connecting to my SQL Server Database remotely from another computer.

I am trying to connect to the database using a VB.Net application that is suppose to be able to interact with it.  I'd say my connection string may be the issue, but I have no problem connecting on the machine the database is on using the connection string.

This is what the connection string looks like though:

```
"Data Source=[IP_ADDRESS],[PORT];Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=SQL_Database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[USER];Password=[PASS]"
```

The error I am getting right now is:

> Database Error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider. error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.).

This is what I have done so far to try to get this to work:

1. I have made sure that the files being run are on not a network/shared drive.
2. I've added an exception for TCP Port 1433 and UDP Port 1434 as Incoming Rules to the Firewall.
3. I've tried disabling the firewall.
4. I have gone into SQL Server Configuration Manager to ensured that the TCP settings are setup properly.

One thing I am not sure about, is that in the Configuration Manager, I have both the SQL Server and SQL Server Browser running, but the SQL Server Agent is unable to start.  Would this cause me my problem?

If not, what else could be my issue?  I need to be able to access this database remotely, but the connection string seems to only work locally.

Comment: SQL Server Agent won't be the problem and isn't needed to connect, but the fact it won't start might be something _else_ is wrong and causing problems.  From the machine you are trying to use that connection string, can you connect with Microsoft SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @sniperd I haven't tried MSMS, but i tried doing a TelNet connection with Putty that wouldn't work.

Comment: Does SQL have `mixed mode` enable and allow remote access?

Comment: @sniperd Yup, Authentication is set to mixed,  and Remote connections are allowed with a 600s timeout.

Comment: Silly things to try: `ping` the box by IP (is that indeed the right IP? network routing can be weird.)  Ping it by name, are you using the right IP?  If you make a `UNC` share on the SQL box can you browse to it, if so then network pathing is OK.

Comment: @sniperd Yeah, I can ping by IP, and by Device Name (which shows me that I'm using the correct IP).  Should I be able to ping by `[DeviceName]\[ServerName]`?  Because that I can't do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176671/discussion-between-skitzafreak-and-sniperd).

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was literally my company's installed network Firewall.  Apparently when I asked if the firewall had been put down for me to test this, "Yes" really meant "No".  Once I got the firewall temporarily disabled I was able to connect to everything perfectly fine.

Comment: Good!  At least you got it figured out :)

Comment: @sniperd God it was so frustrating lol.  I officially hate firewalls :P